# Python QtWebKit save webpage to file

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtwebkit

What's the best and simplest way to save a webpage displayed with QWebView() to file?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtScript import *
import sys
import time

currentfile = "test.htm"
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://news.google.com"))
web.show()
data =  web.page().currentFrame().documentElement().toInnerXml()
open(currentfile,"w").write(data)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the page loading is asynchronous, you have to wait for the `loadFinished` signal before trying to save it.

Then you can retrieve the page content with `web.page().currentFrame().toHtml()` which returns a python unicode string, which you can write to a file with the codecs module:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
import sys
import codecs

class Downloader(QObject):
    # To be emitted when every items are downloaded
    done = Signal()

    def __init__(self, urlList, parent = None):
        super(Downloader, self).__init__(parent)
        self.urlList = urlList
        self.counter = 0        
        # As you probably don't need to display the page
        # you can use QWebPage instead of QWebView
        self.page = QWebPage(self)      
        self.page.loadFinished.connect(self.save)
        self.startNext()

    def currentUrl(self):
        return self.urlList[self.counter][0]

    def currentFilename(self):
        return self.urlList[self.counter][1]

    def startNext(self):
        print "Downloading %s..."%self.currentUrl()
        self.page.mainFrame().load(self.currentUrl())

    def save(self, ok):
        if ok:            
            data = self.page.mainFrame().toHtml()
            with codecs.open(self.currentFilename(), encoding="utf-8", mode="w") as f:
                f.write(data)
            print "Saving %s to %s."%(self.currentUrl(), self.currentFilename())            
        else:
            print "Error while downloading %s\nSkipping."%self.currentUrl()
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter < len(self.urlList):            
            self.startNext()
        else:
            self.done.emit()

urlList = [("http://news.google.com", "google.html"), 
    ("http://www.stackoverflow.com","stack.html"), 
    ("http://www.imdb.com", "imdb.html")]

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
downloader = Downloader(urlList)
# Quit when done
downloader.done.connect(app.quit)

# To view the pages
web = QWebView()
# To prevent user action that would interrupt the current page loading
web.setDisabled(True) 
web.setPage(downloader.page)
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! ;) Just one more quick question: what would be the best way to iterate over multiple links?

Comment: At the end of the `save()` function, instead of having `app.quit()`, you can simply change the file name in `currentfile` and call `web.load()` with the next url.

Comment: that's what I was trying to do, but then it doesn't really wait for the first one to load correctly and generates a download error on the first URL...

Comment: @Cat I updated the code to allow downloading multiple links. The error s you got might have come from variable scope related problems.

Comment: alexisdm, any way to wait for the javascript to finish loading and not just the page? it's still saving only the basic page...

Comment: @Cat You can't easily do that (as stated [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152423/when-is-a-webpage-considered-to-be-loaded-in-the-presence-of-js-etc)). The best you could do, would probably be to temporarily save the page content, wait with a timer and see if there was a change, wait again... until there is no more changes or until another 'maximum' timer times out,  and then finally save the page to disk.

Comment: and how to save the supported files that html has(jpeg,png,js,css. . . ).. . ???
so that when i open saved html it will render properly. ..

Comment: Is there any way to save other object of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that the page needs to be loaded with QtWebKit first? Simply using the command-line utility wget, or curl, would do the job.